# Using Postfix as relay to upgrade encryption

Tags: ssl, postfix, relay

I have some embedded devices which receive no more firmware upgrades. They are only capable of sending mails with TLSv1.1 which is no longer supported by public mail servers.

So my idea is to setup a local Postfix server in the LAN (e.g. on a Raspberry Pi) as a mail relay and use Postfix to receive the mail from the embedded device and forward it to the public mail server. While doing this, encryption should be upgraded from TLSv1.1 to TLSv1.2.

I have done some research but cannot find a good approach how to start with that. Anyone can give me a hint how to approach this?

Answer (score 3):

By default, Postfix accepts TLSv1.0 and above for both receiving (`smtpd`) and sending (`smtp`) mail. This is because the TLS in SMTP is *opportunistic* in nature: it allows fallback to unencrypted connections, which also means it is by design vulnerable to downgrade attacks.

```
$ /usr/sbin/postconf -d | grep -E "^smtp(d)?_tls_(mandatory_)?protocols"
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=TLSv1
smtp_tls_protocols = >=TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=TLSv1
smtpd_tls_protocols = >=TLSv1
```

If you know that the sending systems are always sending messages using TLSv1.1 and the next-hop destination (e.g. a *smarthost*) is always supporting TLSv1.2 (or above), you could harden your configuration:

```
# Accept mail from 192.0.2.0/24
mynetworks = 192.0.2.0/24
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject

# ...requiring encryption (TLSv1.1 or above)
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = >=TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium

# Relay through a smarthost
smtp_tls_security_level = verify
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=TLSv1.2
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
relayhost = [smarthost.example.com]:465
```

If you are not using a smarthost but want to ensure encryption is always used for outbound messages if the receiving system supports encryption and won't need any backwards compatibility, there are two technologies you could familiarize with:

- [RFC 6698](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6698): *The DNS-Based Authentication of Named Entities (DANE) Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol: TLSA*
- [RFC 8461](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8461.html): *SMTP MTA Strict Transport Security (MTA-STS)*